# PHP merge arrays so data is sequential for both sets $a[0] $b[0] $a[1] $b[1]

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

How do you merge arrays so that the output looks like this?

> ($a[0] $b[0] $a[1] $b[1] $a[2] $b[2]...)

Back story to the problem

> I'm trying to build a string with data(strings) from both arrays to
>   build some Sql.

Here is the error set I get from my code.

> Array ( [0] => test@test.test [1] => testpass [2] => )
>
> Array ( [0] => SELECT hosts.Email, hosts.LName, hosts.FName, hosts.ID FROM hosts WHERE >Email = [1] => AND Password = [2] => ; )
>
> SELECT hosts.Email, hosts.LName, hosts.FName, hosts.ID FROM hosts WHERE Email = AND Password = ;test@test.testtestpassblank line
>
> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND Password = ;test@test.testtestpass' at line 1

The line that I need help with is

> foreach ( array_merge( $ArrSql, $input) as $SqlArray) {//merge arrays to build string

I want the output to be like

> $a[0] $b[0] $a[1] $b[1] $a[2] $b[2]...

But what I'm getting is

> $a[0] $a[1] $a[2] $b[0] $b[1] $b[2]...

Okay here is my code bump that might help.

Thank you for your time,
Sam

```
public function ReturnData($Sql, $BindVars) {
    $BindVars[] = '';// needed for pading
    $FilledSql = '';

    $mysqli = DataBase::ConDataBase();
    $ArrSql = explode("?", $Sql);  //splitting the code on '?' so that it can dynamically add the values

    foreach ($BindVars as $value) {
        $input[] = $mysqli->real_escape_string($value);// cleaning the input
    }

    print_r($input);echo "<br>";//testting to see if data is filled
    print_r($ArrSql);echo "<br>". "<br>";//testting to see if array was filled correctly

    foreach ( array_merge( $ArrSql, $input) as $SqlArray) {//merge arrays to build string

        $FilledSql .= $SqlArray; //anding combind strings from the arrays
    }
    echo($FilledSql); Echo  "blank line" . "<br>". "<br>";//
    return $FilledSql;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. Are you trying to print each array element twice? What's the SQL error has to do with this?

Comment: @AmalMurali
 I want to merge two arrays like this ` $a[0] $b[0] $a[1] $b[1] $a[2] $b[2]... `

But what I'm getting is

`$a[0] $a[1] $a[2] $b[0] $b[1] $b[2]...`

Comment: Your SQL error is an [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability.

Comment: @WhiteShadow: Uh, that's exactly what you wrote in the question.

Comment: @MarcB yes I know, but that is because of /my/ code not working.

Comment: @AmalMurali Okay Ill ask like this. How do you merge arrays so that the out put looks like this ($a[0] $b[0] $a[1] $b[1] $a[2] $b[2]...)?

Comment: no, it's because you're building incorrect queries. whatever you do with your array merge problems won't fix the sql error. you have mysql_real_escape_string() in there, but your `testtest` values are still NOT quoted. m_r_e_s doesn't add `'`-quotes to a string. its ONLY function is to escape sql metacharacters WITHIN the string.

Comment: @MarcB Oh. so I still need to use '' around the inputs? LIke this?

>SELECT hosts.Email, hosts.LName,  hosts.FName,  hosts.ID 
                 FROM hosts 
                 WHERE Email = '?' AND Password = '?' ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the foreach you've already implemented, but in a different way. First I'm assuming that you will always have the correct amount of data for each array (e.g. you have arrays with the same amount of keys).

You can do something like this:

```
$resultSql = '';
foreach ( $ArrSql as $key => $sqlString ) {
    $resultSql .= $sqlString . ( ( isset ( $input[$key] ) ) ? $input[$key] : '' );
}
```

This would result in the string that you need. It may be simple but it should work as long as you always use arrays with the same amount of keys.

Comment: I would like to say thank you. It works.
Could you explain this part, I would like to understand the code I use.
` ( ( isset ( $input[$key] ) ) ? $input[$key] : '' ) `

Comment: Sure thing, that is simply a validation, simply a fail safe in case that key does not exist in the $input array, here's an example: say you have a $sql array with keys 1,2,3 and 4 and an $input array with keys 1,2 and 3, when you reach the key 4, it would return an error since $input[4] doesn't exist.

Comment: And the ' '  , is that what it uses if there is no data in the $input[] array at that pointer?

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention it, everything is an "if" statement, this is a brief explanation ( condition ) ? result if true : result if false - so yes, that is the outcome in case that key does not exist.

Comment: Oh that makes sense, I just hadn't seen a If without 'If'.
Its just different from what I have seen, thanks for a new Idea.

Comment: Not a problem, that "kind" of if can be useful in some situations, try playing around with it :)